# MySQL get aggregation in different dimention without more subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL 5.7 and I have a fact table (`CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT VALUES` available at the end of this question):

```
order_date  order_id    fee product_name
2020-11-16  111         10  apple
2020-11-16  222         10  apple
2020-11-16  333         15  banana
2020-11-16  444         12  orange
2020-11-17  555         10  apple
2020-11-17  666         15  banana
```

The target is to calculate the ratio of `sales of one product / daily sales`. I can do this by calculate them in 2 subqueries and then join together like:

```
    SELECT a.order_date,product_name,cnt_product,cnt_total,
    ROUND(cnt_product/cnt_total,4) AS ratio 
    FROM
    (SELECT order_date,product_name,COUNT(1) AS cnt_product
    FROM test
    GROUP BY 1,2) a
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT order_date,COUNT(1) AS cnt_total
    FROM test
    GROUP BY 1) b
    ON a.order_date = b.order_date
```

Is there more elegant way or more efficient way to do this in ONE subquery?

---

CREATE TABLES

```
CREATE TABLE test (
order_date DATETIME,
order_id INT,
fee INT,
product_name VARCHAR(50)
)
```

INSERT VALUES

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('2020-11-16',111,10,'apple'),('2020-11-16',222,10,'apple'),('2020-11-16',333,15,'banana'),('2020-11-16',444,12,'orange'),('2020-11-17',555,10,'apple'),('2020-11-17',666,15,'banana')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT order_date, 
       t1.product_name,
       COUNT(1) AS cnt_product,
       t2.cnt_total,
       ROUND(COUNT(1) / t2.cnt_total, 4) AS ratio 
FROM test t1
JOIN ( SELECT order_date, 
              COUNT(1) AS cnt_total
       FROM test
       GROUP BY 1 ) t2 USING (order_date)
GROUP BY 1, 2, 4
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=79bde7e5841310169b824640a3e4f934)

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 5.7, you cannot use window functions, which would look like:

```
SELECT order_date, product_name, COUNT(*) AS cnt_product,
       COUNT(*) / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY order_date) as ratio
FROM test
GROUP BY order_date, product_name;
```

However, you don't have that capability in 5.7.  Your query is okay (although I would recommend formatting it so it is more readable).  That said, the `LEFT JOIN` can just be an `INNER JOIN`.

You might consider upgrading to a more recent version of MySQL.